# Dependency Injection Container

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Подскажите пожалуйста, при использовании DI-контейнера возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Должен ли DI-контейнер быть единым для всего приложения ?

Т.е. могу ли я в контейнер добавить сервисы в одном месте приложения, а использовать в другом ?

Например, у меня есть модуль `Order`, в котором много классов, разных ajax-обработчиков файлов и т.д. 
Можно ли во всех файлах модуля использовать сервисы контейнера ?

на каком этапе приложения (или модуля) нужно добавлять сервисы в контейнер, ведь нельзя же в любом файле модуля добавлять сервисы, т.к. при попытке получения сервиса из контейнера, может сервиса там не оказаться, т.к. на текущем этапе его там еще нет. Следовательно, нужно при запуске определенного модуля заполнять контейнер сервисами ?

2. Если вышенаписанное правда, и для целого модуля нужно использовать единый контейнер с свервисами, то как тогда будут все файлы видеть контейнер ? Контейнер должен быть глобальным ? Иили singleton ?

объясните пожалуйста, очень долгое время не могу найти ответы на свои вопросы.
А именно не понимаю процесс работы с контейнером. 
Буду очень благодарен если распишете все по шагам. Когда и что делается, для чего, какая область видимости для контейнера и т.д.

Желательно не рассматривать какую-то конкретную реализацию контейнера.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/278049/

Comment: @KirillKorushkin спасибо! я как раз сегодня читал эту статью. Но к сожалению не нашел ответы на мои вопросы(

Comment: Можете помочь найти ответы на них пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Да,контейнер един и все сервисы создаются через него; Добавление происходит на этапе запуска приложения, то есть в приложении где-то есть единая точка входа, там и создается контейнер и регистрируются все возможные зависимости;
2. Контейнер не видят все сервисы, это он видет их все. То есть в контейнере зарегистрированы все сервисы и он их создает. Обычно Сервисам не нужно к нему обращаться, т.к. все, что им нужно, все их зависимости и параметры, им передает контейнер через конструктор при создании. Иногда может возникнуть необходимость какому-то сервису обратиться к контейнеру, тогда этот контейнер может передать сам себя через конструктор, если сервис его запрашивает. То есть все сервисы все получают через конструктор автоматически, в том числе и сервис контейнера. К примеру есть у вас модуль order, которому нужно куча зависимостей для своей работы, на старте приложения мы регистрируем и сам этот Order и все нужные ему сервисы в контейнере, после чего просто запрашиваем сам Order  у контейнера что-то вроде

   order = Container.GetService(Order);
   И получаем полностью готовый order, со всеми его зависимостями, созданные автоматически.

Пример класса Order, которому нужен logger:

```
class Order
{
$private $logger;
    public function __construct(Logger $logger) {
$this->logger = $logger;
}
}
```

И после этого в любом месте можно им воспользоваться

```
$this->logger.LogInfo();
```

Если же вам захотелось получить логгер из контейнера, что является скорее плохой практикой, то в конструктор может быть передан непосредственно контейнер

```
class Order
{
$private $logger;
private $container;
    public function __construct(Container $container) {
$this->container =$container;
// И где угодно можем получить сервис
$this->logger = $this->container.GetService(Logger);
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Стало на много понятнее!

Только один момент непонятен еще:
например в единой точке входа в приложение, в файле `bootstrap.php` после подключения файла композера `autoload.php` я создаю DI-контейнер, например `Pimple`:

`<?php include '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$container = new Pimple();
// и тут же задаю в контейнер все сервисы и зависимости`

Далее мне нужно в классе `Order`, который в проект подключается через автозагрузчик использовать контейнер.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как в файле с классом будет доступен контейнер, который я создал и инициализировал в другом файле ?


Нужно писать `global $container;` ? Или как ?

Comment: А зачем вам в классе Order получать контейнер? Нужно представить эту ситуацию, вам в классе Order обычно контейнер не нужен, т.к. контейнер вы используете чтобы получить какие-то сервисы, но все сервисы будут инжектированы самим контейнером через конструктор в идеале, вам не нужен там контейнер, но если он вдруг будет нужен, то он может быть инжектирован через конструктор точно так же как и любой другой сервис, то есть у вас в конструкторе кроме всего прочего будет прописан и контейнер.

Comment: То есть все классы, которые вы получаете в Order создаются контейнером и передаются ордеру в конструктор, внутри order никакие сервисы не создаются, в том числе это верно и для самого контейнера. Думаю, чтобы лучше понять, вам нужно взять какой-то туториал по какому-то конкретному контейнеру и попытаться его выполнить, тут конкретика лучше абстракции.

Comment: Например в методе `make` класса `Order`, нужно добавить какую-то запись в логи.
Насколько я понял из разных примеров работы с IoC контейнерами, то мне нужно получить сервис логгера, и добавить данные в лог. Т.е. так: `$logger = $container["logger"];  $logger->log($message);` Или я что-то не так понимаю ? Может так нельзя делать?

Comment: Нужно в каждый класс, который использует сервис логирования, мне нужно через конструктор передавать `$container` ?

Comment: Бывают моменты, когда так приходится сделать, но это скорее антипаттерн. В вашем примере Order должен получить Logger через конструктор, а чтобы получить доступ к контейнеру, что не самая лучшая практика, его тоже нужно получить через конструктор. Добавлю пример такого класса в ответ.

Comment: @KonstantinGaliakhmetov спасибо большое за ответы и пример!

почему получение логгер из контейнера является антипаттерном ? 

Может посоветуете статьи или литературу, как бы я смог более детально разобраться с паттерном dependency injection и контейнерами ?

Comment: Когда вы передаете нужные зависимости в конструктор, то четко контролируете, что ему нужно, т.е. увидив определение класса сразу можете сказать, что ему понадобиться и вы легко сможете его замокать, когда будете писать тесты. На эту тему на хабре недавно была статья: https://habr.com/ru/post/465395/

Comment: Что же касается статьи на тему Di вообще, не знаю, что посоветовать, насамом деле об этом очень много написано и легко гуглиться. По моему мнению, нужно просто взять туториал по какому-нибудь контейнеру, выполнить его, и написать unit тест для класса с зависимостями, тогда вам сразу станет очевидно какой смысл в DI и как оно работает.

Comment: @KonstantinGaliakhmetov я попробовал как вы и написали, поставить какой-то DI-контейнер и на его основе написать что-то. У меня все равно ничего не получилось: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021666/
 помогите пожалуйста)