# Dependency Injection Container, попробовал на практике - не понял смысла

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Всем привет, начал изучать паттерн dependency injection, вроде, все понятно и логично.

Насколько понял, для удобного управления зависимости используются специальные контейнеры.

Очень долгое время я не мог понять, как же используется этот контейнер на практике, какая область видимости у контейнера, и в какой момент в контейнер добавляют сервисы ?

Задав эти вопросы на форумах, мне посоветовали взять любой DI-контейнер, и попробовать с ним поработать, тогда и станет понятно.

Решил я взять очень простой DI-контейнер, от разработчиков symfony - [Pimple](https://pimple.symfony.com/).

Написал класс `SystemBlock` (системный блок) с 3-4 зависимостями:

- Блок питания
- Видеокарта
- Процессор
- Операционная система

Пример вызова класса `SystemBlock` без контейнера:

```
<?php
use Less\SystemBlock;

$systemBlock = new SystemBlock\SystemBlock(
    new SystemBlock\GigabytePower,
    new SystemBlock\GeForceVideo,
    new SystemBlock\IntelProcessor
);


$os = new SystemBlock\LinuxOS;
$os->setUser(new SystemBlock\OSUser("Вася", "Vasya", true));

$systemBlock->setOperatingSystem($os);
$systemBlock->start();
```

и пример с использованием контейнера:

```
<?php
use Less\SystemBlock;

$container = new \Pimple\Container;

$container["power"] = function ($c) {
    return new SystemBlock\GigabytePower;
};

$container["video"] = function ($c) {
    return new SystemBlock\GeForceVideo;
};

$container["processor"] = function ($c) {
    return new SystemBlock\IntelProcessor;
};

$container["system_block"] = function ($c) {
    return new SystemBlock\SystemBlock(
        $c["power"],
        $c["video"],
        $c["processor"]
    );
};

$systemBlock = $container["system_block"];

$os = new SystemBlock\LinuxOS;
$os->setUser(new SystemBlock\OSUser("Вася", "Vasya", true));

$systemBlock->setOperatingSystem($os);
$systemBlock->start();
```

Файлы с классами и интерфейсами выложил на [GitHub](https://github.com/raxewira/tmp)

Возникшие вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я понял, что сервисы в контейнер мы добавляем в файле единой точки входа в приложение ?

Что делать, если у меня у случая, когда нужно вызвать нужный сконфигурированный сервис загрузки товаров на сайт, например:

1.1. Загрузка происходит через файл `bin/import.php` при запуске скрипта через крон.

1.2. При загрузка происходит через админку `admin/import.php` сайта по кнопке.

В первом и втором случае мне необходим один и тот же сконфигурированный сервис.
Мне необходимо в начале каждого файла `bin/import.php` и `admin/import.php` добавлять сервисы в контейнер и конфигурировать, или нужно вынести в отдельный общий файл ? Покажите пример пожалуйста, как это делается, и какие могут быть нюансы ?

2. Из моих примеров управления зависимостями через контейнер и вручную, я не заметил никакой разницы. В чем преимущество контейнера ? Почему то, что я сделал вручную - неудобно ?

или контейнер нужен в тех случаях, когда один и тотже сервис используется несколько раз ? И в будущем удобно будет тестировать ? Заменил только в контейнере на тестовый сервис ?

И честно говоря, для меня самое сложное - это понять пункт

В каком месте приложения нужна инициализация контейнера ? Можно ли выносить в отдельный файл? Как подключать этот файл ? И т.д.

За помощь и развернутый ответ буду благодарен!

Comment: Вручную неудобно будет, создавать зависимости прямо из конструктора класса, если ваш контейнер такое умеет и dependency injection это не паттерн по мне это больше инструмент, а вот "Service Locator" который лежит в основе контейнера и есть паттерн

Answer (score 0):

> Правильно ли я понял, что сервисы в контейнер мы добавляем в файле
>   единой точки входа в приложение ?

Зависит от того, как напишите код. Можно не прямо в точке входа разместить сервисы, а в другом файле и подключить его во фронт контроллере. Но это всё уже давно реализовано в самом фреймворке Symfony.

> Что делать, если у меня у случая, когда нужно вызвать нужный
>   сконфигурированный сервис загрузки товаров на сайт, например

А почему бы просто не создать отдельный роут для загрузки товаров?

> Из моих примеров управления зависимостями через контейнер и вручную, я
>   не заметил никакой разницы. В чем преимущество контейнера ? Почему то,
>   что я сделал вручную - неудобно ?

У вас простой пример с небольшим количеством зависимостей. Представьте, что у вас один класс зависит от другого, а тот в свою очередь от другого и так далее.
Чтобы создать объект такого класса, нужно было бы каждый раз инстанциировать несколько других классов.

Второе преимущество контейнеров в том, что объекты создаются только тогда когда вы их используете.

Третье преимущество - возможность работать с единственным экземпляром класса без использования Singleton.

Для более детального объяснения, советую почитать хорошую серию статей по DI с примером реализации на PHP: http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html